# Why is the `Array` class accessible from classes that do not extend it?

Tags: ruby

The `Array` class can be accessed from the `Module` class:

```
module Foo
  def arr
    @arr = []
  end

  def add_to_arr(obj)
    arr.push(obj)
  end
end
```

but `Module` is not a subclass of `Array`. The module definition above is legal. How can methods from the `Array` class be accessed from the `Module` class when `Module` is not a subclass of `Array`?

Comment: Are you referring to the fact you can access `[]`, or that you can call `arr` in your methods?

Comment: Extention, inclusion, prepending, inheritance are all irrelevant. Such call is always possible when you have an explicit receiver with public methods.

Comment: It'd be a pretty useless system if you only could call methods from within hierarchy.

Comment: Ruby has basic data types (Booleans,Symbols,Numbers,Strings,Arrays,Hashes). All data types are based on classes. You can access these classes from everywhere.

Comment: Are you referring to `[]` or to `push`?

Comment: Why is this question upvoted?

Comment: Also, `Foo` is not the `Module` class, it is an instance of the `Module` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` is an object of the `Array` class, therefore it has access to all the instance methods of the class, such as [`Array#push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-push):

```
[].class # => Array

[].public_methods
=> [:fill, :assoc, :rassoc, :uniq, :uniq!, :compact, :compact!, :flatten, :to_h, :flatten!, :shuffle!, :shuffle, :include?, :combination, :repeated_permutation, :permutation, :product, :sample, :repeated_combination, :bsearch_index, :bsearch, :select!, :&, :*, :+, :-, :sort, :count, :find_index, :select, :reject, :collect, :map, :pack, :first, :any?, :reverse_each, :zip, :take, :take_while, :drop, :drop_while, :cycle, :insert, :|, :index, :rindex, :replace, :clear, :<=>, :<<, :==, :[], :[]=, :reverse, :empty?, :eql?, :concat, :reverse!, :inspect, :delete, :length, :size, :each, :slice, :slice!, :to_ary, :to_a, :to_s, :dig, :hash, :at, :fetch, :last, :push, :pop, :shift, :unshift, :frozen?, :each_index, :join, :rotate, :rotate!, :sort!, :collect!, :map!, :sort_by!, :keep_if, :values_at, :delete_at, :delete_if, :reject!, :transpose, :find, :entries, :sort_by, :grep, :grep_v, :detect, :find_all, :flat_map, :collect_concat, :inject, :reduce, :partition, :group_by, :all?, :one?, :none?, :min, :max, :minmax, :min_by, :max_by, :minmax_by, :member?, :each_with_index, :each_entry, :each_slice, :each_cons, :each_with_object, :chunk, :slice_before, :slice_after, :slice_when, :chunk_while, :lazy, :instance_of?, :public_send, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?, :remove_instance_variable, :private_methods, :kind_of?, :instance_variables, :tap, :public_method, :singleton_method, :is_a?, :extend, :define_singleton_method, :method, :to_enum, :enum_for, :===, :=~, :!~, :respond_to?, :freeze, :display, :object_id, :send, :nil?, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :itself, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :trust, :untrusted?, :methods, :protected_methods, :public_methods, :singleton_methods, :!, :!=, :__send__, :equal?, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__id__]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create arrays a few different ways in Ruby:

`Array.new` instantiates a new object of class Array.

`Array` by itself calls the method `Array` on the Kernel object which returns an array http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array

`[]` is just syntactic sugar for the literal construction of an Array object. https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4df168074c9e80822b4326a4539600ae7dbe0adb/array.c#L5791

Both Array and Kernel are part of the core library and are therefore available to all objects.

EDIT based on @stephan's correction

Comment: `[]` is *not* syntactic sugar for `Kernel::Array`. The latter is a conversion function. Try `Kernel::Array(1..5)` vs. `[1..5]`